# i want to change backgroud image of the navigationbar when ever i move to the other view in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app were I have to place images on the navigation-bar, whenever the user moves to the other view, different images have to appear in navigation bar. Could someone provide me with some guidance how to do this?

Comment: how did you implement this in your project? any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more of a generic approach.

Create a Category for UINavigationBar and in the".h" file

```
@interface  UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image;

@end
```

and in the ".m" file

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

-(void)setBackgroundImage: (UIImage*)image
{

    if (image)
    {

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage: image];
        aTabBarBackground.frame = CGRectMake(60,0, 200, 45);//Frame depends upon you 
        [self addSubview:img];
        [img release];
    }

}
@end
```

And then from every Controller's 'viewwillAppear'  you can do something like this:

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: @"abc.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code ...

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar=[[self navigationController]navigationBar];
UIImage *backgroundImg =[UIImage imageNamed:@"example.png"];
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

add this code in **viewwillappear** and give the image name to be displayed instead of example.png